Powerapps Form does not map correctly fields
I have a sharepoint list with two columns : "utilisateur" and "role". Both are required.
I created a form with the mode "New" in powerapps. In this form there are two input : a dropdown and a combobox. Both are inside a DataCard and both DataCard have the property "update" set to .Selected and DataField properties are set to "utilisateur" and "role".

When I select an "utilisateur", it correctly change the input value (I show it with a Text item)

But when I check my sharepoint list it show an empty item :

It should automaticaly map the input value to the item value in the list.

Did you insert Combobox and dropdown by selecting insert option from the menu in the form? Or your Forms Dataset is pointing to your sharepoint list? Share complete screenshot of your screen and explain exactly what you are trying to do and what error you are having

I inserted them via the insert menu

That's what I was expecting and the reason you need to use little more detailed Update formula otherwise all the datacardvalues are tied with the Form's datasource and on Form's submission gets updated.

The update properties of my DataCards had to be a little more detailled :
Role dropdown
{
    '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference";
    Id: Dropdown2.Selected.ID
}

Utilisateur combobox
{
    '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser";
    Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & ComboBox1.Selected.Mail;
    DisplayName: ComboBox1.Selected.DisplayName;
    Email: ComboBox1.Selected.Mail
}


Depending on the column type of the SharePoint column, you will need to specify the Value property from the selected dropdown. If the SharePoint column is a Choice column, then
Combobox1.Selected
should work. But if it's a text column, it can't deal with the object that the Choice item is set to. You need to further dig into the Value.
Combobox1.Selected.Value

"utilisateur" is a "person or group" column and "role" is "search" with list "roles" and column "id" but when I try to modify DropDown2.Selected to DropDown2.Selected.id it says it needs a Record

Yes. these are complex object types. It is not clear how your comboboxes are configured, i.e. how are the items in the comboboxes defined? Depending on these, you will need to take additional steps to populate a SharePoint person column or what ever column type the role is. In short: Your question doesn't have enough information for a complete answer.

I'm using office365 to get the list of person :
'Utilisateursd’Office365'.SearchUser({searchTerm: ComboBox1.SearchText}). My role dropdown is just a list of roles based on another sharepoint list so items are from a sharepoint datasource. The role column is a "lookup column"
